# Return nth child of a radio button group

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have three radio buttons in a group thus:

```
<div class="form-check ml-4">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="1" id="1" value="First">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="1">First</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check ml-4">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="1" id="2" value="Second">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="2">Second</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check ml-4">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="1" id="3" value="Third">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="3">Third</label>
</div>
```

Using jQuery, how would I retrieve the nth-child number of a checked radio button in the group?

I tried this:

```
(($(find("input[type=radio]:checked")).attr('nth-child()')))
```

Comment: What have you tried? You should be able to combine `.closest()` and `.index()` to get the index of the containing div.

Comment: I tried this:   (($(find("input[type=radio]:checked")).attr('nth-child()')))

Comment: `nth-child` is not an attribute. The `.index()` method will tell you the position of an element among its siblings. But you need to get the position of the div that contains the button, not the button itself.

Comment: @Krampus It is an online food menu. Entrées include sides. If a user selects an entrée that does not include a side that was previously chosen I want to preserve the chosen side and check it in a different group of sides. All sides in all groups are in the same location.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the position of the `div` that wraps around the radio button, not the button itself.

`nth-child` is not an attribute of an element. The `.index()` method will return the position of an element among its siblings.

```
$(":radio:checked").closest("div.form-check").index()
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late, but you didn't explain the purpose of getting the nth child. My guess is that you would like to the the value of the selected radio button.

With the name of the radio button group you can just ask for `form.n1.value` there n1 is the name.

Note that the value for an id attribute should start with a letter ([the id attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)).

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('change', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  console.log(form.n1.value);
});
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <div class="form-check ml-4">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="n1" id="id1" value="First">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="id1">First</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check ml-4">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="n1" id="id2" value="Second">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="id2">Second</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check ml-4">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="n1" id="id3" value="Third">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="id3">Third</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on id's. I wasn't aware of that. I was able to get the value of the checked radio button. I was looking for the index number. I appreciate your input.

Comment: @Stephen My issue here is that I don't understand the purpose of getting the index number. To me, it sounds like a bad design of an HTML form. I get that you would like some values to stick somehow. Maybe if you update your question with a more detailed example, that would be great.